# Retain powershell session to Office 365 between commands

Tags: powershell, azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I am trying to put together a simple app using PowerShell forms, with buttons to run commands against an Office 365 tenant.

The first button they need to hit connects them to Azure AD, then the other buttons will run the commands.

The problem I have is maintaining the PS session. The form loads, I press the button to kick of the `Connect-AzureAD` command and it connects fine. Then when I press another button to run another command such as `get-msoluser` it complains I am not connected to Azure AD.

So how do I use the session I have established from the first button click? I want to connect once when I first load the app and keep that connection for all actions I perform until I close the form.

Comment: Including the relevant parts of your code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help us diagnose your problem.

Comment: No worries I will post the code when I get home.  It's nothing special, just a form with 2 buttons on at the moment, 1 to connect to 365 and one to run another command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Connect-AzureAD` is a cmdlet of Azure AD V2 Powershell, `Get-MsolUser` is a cmdlet of MSOnline PowerShell 1.0.

**They are two different cmdlet for two module**.Before using `Get-MsolUser`, you must call the `Connect-MsolService` cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.

If you want to use both Azure AD V2 Powershell and MSOline Powershell 1.0, you must use  Connect-AzureAD and Connect-MsolService first.

Comment: and now I feel like a prat.  I really should have known that!